# Django filter query with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to filter query based on three user inputs. Depart City, Arrive City  and Date. Depart City and Arrive city are on the same table called Route while the TravelDate is a foreign key in Route. 
My model

```
 class TravelDate(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(null = True)
    interval = models.IntegerField(null = True) 



class Route(models.Model): 
    depart_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    arrive_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
    traveldate = models.ForeignKey(TravelDate)
```

My View

```
def newpage(request):
    if 'origin' in request.GET and request.GET['origin']:
        q = request.GET['origin']
        c = request.GET['dest']
        d = request.GET['travelDate']

        results = Route.objects.filter(depart_city=q, arrive_city=c)

        return render(request,'busapp/newpage.html', {'results': results})
    else:
        return render(request, 'busapp/newpage.html',{})
```

In Views how can i make one query that will filter depart_city, arrive_city, and TravelDate of those routes based on user inputed. If a bus is available on that date from city A to city B will be calculated by doing doing something like this `if (d - TravelDate.start_date)% TravelDate.interval =0` then display the results to the user.

I cannot get this right. I'm new to Django and trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Keep interval as IntegerField

views.py

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    q = request.GET['origin']
    c = request.GET['dest']
    d = request.GET['travelDate']
    # d format is '20171122',convert str to date
    start_date = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y%m%d").date()
    results = Route.objects.filter(depart_city=q, arrive_city=c)
    routes = []
    for route in results:
        if (start_date > date) and ((start_date - route.traveldate.start_date) % timedelta(days=route.traveldate.interva)) == timedelta(days=0):
            routes.append(route)
    return render(request,'busapp/newpage.html', {'results': routes})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:                  if(d - route.traveldate.start_date)% route.traveldate.interval == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'datetime.date

Comment: you should use timedelta to calculate whether the route is your wanted,so the unit of interval is what?

Comment: interval is how often the bus does that route. So 1 means the bus does that route everyday since any (date - start_date) % 1 =0.    2 means every other day. I'm new to python/Django and don't know what timedelta is but will look it up now and see how I can use it

Comment: your start_date means the route is offer online since that day and interval 1 means 1 bus a day,interval 2 means 1 bus two day?

Comment: Yes, the start_date means the route is offered online since that day. interval 1 means that the bus  goes from point A to B everyday. Interval 2 means that the bus goes from point A to point B every other day. Lets say the user picks 2017-11-26 as his travel date and I have registered the bus online since 2017-11-20. Then we use  if (travelDate - start_date)%2=0 display the bus info (time, driver..) to the user.  So if we have ((2017-11-26)-(2017-11-20))%2 will give us 0 and we will display the info to the user.

Comment: But if the user decides to search for buses on 27th then we won't get 0 as an answer for this specific bus  so that means the bus is not available that day. In short what i'm trying to do is repeating events. If the user searches for a route from A -> B a month from now I want to display the buses that will be available that day. If you know a better way of doing repeating events please let me know.

Comment: SELECT busapp_route.depart_city, busapp_route.arrive_city, busapp_driver.first_name, busapp_schedule.depart_time 
FROM (((busapp_route INNER JOIN busapp_driver ON busapp_route.driver_id = busapp_driver.id) 
INNER JOIN busapp_schedule ON busapp_route.schedule_id = busapp_schedule.id)
INNER JOIN busapp_traveldate ON busapp_route.traveldate_id = busapp_traveldate.id) 
WHERE busapp_route.depart_city='Tropoje' AND busapp_route.arrive_city='Tirane'
AND (DATEDIFF('2017-11-26', busapp_traveldate.start_date) % busapp_traveldate.interval = 0);

Comment: That didn't work either man but I what I'm trying to do is the equivalent of this MySQL script in Django Queries